# Changing behavior of bash prompt when functioning as root

Tags: command-line, bash, bashrc, prompt

Before you click away, this isn't the typical "how do I make my bash prompt have color" question.  I've already customized my bash prompt to look like this:

```
[user @ host]----[$(pwd)]
$
```

where everything in brackets is light blue, and everything else (including $) is black by adding the following to my ~/.bashrc file

```
# Turn the prompt symbol red if the user is root
if [ $(id -u) -eq 0 ];
then # you are root, make the prompt red
    PS1="[\e[01;34m\u @ \h\e[00m]----[\e[01;34m$(pwd)\e[00m]\n\e[01;31m#\e[00m "
else
    PS1="[\e[01;34m\u @ \h\e[00m]----[\e[01;34m$(pwd)\e[00m]\n$ "
fi
```

The goal is to make it such that the only thing that changes when I use 'sudo su' is that the black $ changes into a red #.  I've looked in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile to see if there is just a line to comment out, but there is a bunch of stuff about debian_chroot that I don't understand, and I don't want to screw something up.  How can I accomplish what I want?

P.S. This is what I want the prompt to look like as root

```
[user @ host]----[$(pwd)]
(red)#
```

edit: Mark this solved, appending the above code to ~/.bashrc while root accomplished my goal. Also, in the above code, $(pwd) only displays the home directory (I guess because that is the working directory when the terminal is opened), and never updates.  Replacing $(pwd) with \w fixes this, but displays the home directory as `~`, which I was trying to avoid.

Comment: Are you using $pwd or $PWD?

Comment: It'll fail to wrap lines correctly since you did not tell bash that you were using non-printable characters. Enclose non-printable characters, such as `\e[01;31m`, in `\[...\]`. This is explained under PROMPTING in the manual. Also see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/053

Comment: Reason why `pwd` did not work in the prompt is, that you need to escape the dollar-sign, otherwise `$(pwd)` will be executed _before_ the content is placed in $PS1. You can test it with this: 
`PS1="\$(pwd) "`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It will also depend on how you become the root user. You need to make the change in the root user's .bashrc if you are using something like `su - root` or `sudo -i`, where you read in the environment.

With `sudo -s`, you should be reading your own .bashrc.

Consider adding some printf or echo statements to debug your code, to tell you when it has executed.

Use the `id` command to make sure you are who you think you are:

```
root@tau:~# id
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
```

Comment: I'm using `sudo su`

Comment: `sudo su` reads ~root/.bashrc (at least as currently implemented on my 13.04 system).

Answer (score 3):

To change the colour of the prompt to red for root, I modified the `.bashrc` file, following the examples in this thread.

```
regularuser@myubuntubox:~$ sudo su - 
root@myubuntubox:~# vim .bashrc
```

Then, in vim, search for the final appearance of `PS1` assignment, and add this following it (note that it updates the value of `$PS1` so that other previous lines do not need to be modified, and the change is easily revertible):

```
# Set RED prompt
PS1="\[\e[01;31m\]$PS1\[\e[00m\]"
```

Answer (score 2):

Following belacqua's valid answer https://askubuntu.com/a/305053/12218, by issuing sudo su the root's  .bashrc is loaded.

You can check this by issuing `sudo su` followed by `cd ~` you will see that you are at root's home directory.

Using `sudo su` you log in as root (su = switch user) in contrary with
`sudo do some administrative task` as user with elevated privileges.

So by using `sudo su` you become the actual root and the changes made to environment are changes made specifically to root, i.e: `sudo su` followed by `vim .bashrc`.

Answer (score 1):

Following may help

```
export PS1='`[ $(id -u) == "0" ] && echo "#" || echo ">"` '
```

This will show `'> '` for normal user and `'# '` for root. This still needs to be in root's `.bashrc` too.

Comment: A similar thing can be accomplished with `\$` which shows `#` if root and `$` otherwise. `\$` isn't very useful though since it's not customizable.

Answer (score 0):

as others said previously in this topic "su -" and "sudo -i" or "sudo -s" using the .bashrc from /root directory so you should add to the end of `/root/.bashrc` file.
I just write a sample my be it could make this easier for newbies.

```
# enable color when you login as root user with sudo -i or sudo -s
# this is just a test and I'am not sure if it works well
if [ `whoami` == 'root' ]; then
        # Set RED prompt [\033[01;31m\]
        PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;31m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
        # Set GREEN  prompt [\033[01;32m\]
        PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
fi
```